# How do I figure out what the key properties for a type are in an ObjectContext?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a entity type through a Type object and the ObjectContext. From those, how do I get the key property names (not their values)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();

// Get entity set for current entity type
var entitySet = objectSet.EntitySet;
// Get names of the entity's key properties
var keyNames = entitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(e => e.Name).ToList();
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273416/entity-framework-simple-generic-getbyid-but-has-differents-pk-name/5278684#5278684) is some example how to use this to create generic method for loading entity by key (the example uses only entities with single key but it can be extended).

Comment: This fails when the TEntity is not the base class in a tree of classes, though I can work that out through reflection.

Comment: Yes because for hierarchies you must use object set for the base type.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally the following works, though is wordier than Ladislav's answer, but has the benefit of working on any type without additional reflection work:

```
using System.Data.Metadata.Edm;
...
IEnumerable<string> keyNames = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace
    .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
    .Single(edmType => edmType.FullName == type.FullName)
    .KeyMembers
    .Select(e => e.Name)
```