# Finding the Changeset in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using EF4 repositories in a ASP.NET MVC3/WCF application. I am using the Unit of Work pattern to apply changes to the database

One of the user requirements is to create a ticket/email with a list of changes to the entity. Is there a way I can detect only the changed properties on an entity in the following function?

```
public void UpdateTrackedEntity<T>(T modifiedEntity) where T : class
{
    var set = CreateObjectSet<T>();
    set.ApplyCurrentValues(modifiedEntity);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way:

```
public void UpdateTrackedEntity<T>(T modifiedEntity) where T : class
{
    var set = CreateObjectSet<T>();
    set.ApplyCurrentValues(modifiedEntity);
    var entry = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(modifiedEntity);
    // entry has two collections: CurrentValues (those you applied) and 
    // OriginalValues (those loaded from DB)
    // It also have method GetModifiedProperties to get collection of modified 
    // property names.
}
```

Check [ObjectStateEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstateentry.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I get the following error when I make the GetObjectStateEntry call, The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type '<T>', T being my Entity type

Comment: @kolhapuri: Yes that is correct. You must pass the attached instance to the `ObjectStateManager`. Are you using POCOs or EntityObjects?

Comment: To give you a little bit more info..   I changed my functions as follows. The originalentity exists in the Objectset.                      Context.Users.Attach(originalEntity);
var entry = Context.UpdateTrackedEntity<User>(modifiedEntity);
return entry.GetModifiedProperties();                          public ObjectStateEntry UpdateTrackedEntity<T>(T modifiedEntity) where T : class
        {
            var set = CreateObjectSet<T>();
            set.ApplyCurrentValues(modifiedEntity);
            return ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(modifiedEntity);
        }

Comment: @kolhapuri: Tyr using the second overload of `GetObjectSateEntry` which accepts `EntityKey`. Getting entity key from POCO is little bit hareder. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273416/entity-framework-simple-generic-getbyid-but-has-differents-pk-name/5278684#5278684 I describe there how to get it for another purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your domain service object is DsrvObj

```
 DsrvObj.EntityContainer.GetChanges() 
                      ...GetChanges().AddedEntities.Count /*also possible for modified and romoved ones*/
```

//These ones could be beneficial also

```
           DsrvObj.HasChanges
           DsrvObj.MS_EntitySets.HasChanges
```

will give you the changeset, But interestingly I can't see some modified boolean fields on this changeset today! Finally I realized that for instance if a DataGrid is in EditMode your changes doesnt go to changeset,After end edit it goes to changeset.

implement it ,test it ,Trust it!