# Generic check if something has changed with entity framework and repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, repository

My update method will always update since I have to set the LastModified date. I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically check if some values have changed.

My **state objects** look like this:

```
public partial class Action : IEntity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

The **interface** I use looks like this:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    long Id { get; set; }        
    DateTime Created { get; set; }
    DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    DateTime? Deleted { get; set; }       
}
```

My **update method** looks like this (The changes are saved later):

```
    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        var attachedEntity = DbSet.Find(entity.Id);

        if (attachedEntity != null)
        {
            var attachedEntry = DbContext.Entry(attachedEntity);

            entity.Created = attachedEntity.Created;
            entity.LastModified = DateTime.Now;

            attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            entity.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

So it will actually perform a generic update for every object that is passed as T with the the `IEntity` Interface. However it performs the update every single call to this method because the `LastModified` value is changed. Resulting in **many update queries** like these:

```
exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[BiztalkEntity]
set [LastModified] = @0
where ([Id] = @1)
',N'@0 datetime2(7),@1 bigint',@0='2013-05-17 11:22:52.4183349',@1=10007
```

Could you tell me how to prevent the query being executed every single time?

Comment: [Sort of like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5806708/7724)

Comment: @bzlm thanks for the quick respond, but this actually works. I just want to know how to check for the changes, and then not set the value of last modified, so it won't update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you delay the setting of `LastModified` and let Entity Framework give you all the entities that have been changed just prior to the changes being sent to the database.

You can override the `SaveChanges()` method of `DbContext`

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        //you may need this line depending on your exact configuration
        //ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        foreach (DbEntityEntry o in GetChangedEntries())
        {
            IEntity entity = o.Entity as IEntity;
            entity.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    private IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry> GetChangedEntries()
    {
        return new List<DbEntityEntry>(
            from e in ChangeTracker.Entries()
            where e.State != System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged
            select e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds ok, but I don't think I can get an IEntity out of DbEntityEntry or can I? Trying it now

Comment: @NickN. DbEntityEntry.Entity http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.entity(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: @NickN. it has never given me any issue.

Comment: Where does the `ChangeTracker` come from? As in what namespace?

Comment: It does not affect the queries for me, do you think it's because it still detect changes? Now the `LastModified` property is still set for every single object that is saved and that's a good thing. But I just don't want some to get saved in the first place. Since they are not really changed

Comment: @NickN. it must be due to the line 'dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified' where you're basically saying "it's definitely changed". Try attaching without changing the `State`.