# DbContext Generic Method to Find Key Members

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Is there a way to find `Key Members` of an entity (`TEntity`) when using CodeFirst (`DbContext`) on a generic context similar to `ObjectContext`?

I can see how it's done using `ObjectContext` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273416/entity-framework-simple-generic-getbyid-but-has-differents-pk-name).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for the confusion, it seems like even with Code First approach we can find the key members on an entity using the object context as shown below:

```
var ObjectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext;
var ObjectSet = ObjectContext .CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
var EntitySet = ObjectSet.EntitySet;
var KeyMembers = EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers;
```